# Tensorflow Keras: Training Holting on model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, freeze

I am new to tensorflow and python, so I'm sure its just something stupid. But when I try to train my model with model.fit(), after a random number of training iterations it freezes. GPU usage goes to zero, and no error message is shown to indicate where the error is. The model I am trying to train is as follows:

```
SizeOfInput = 50
VocabSize = 8000
EmbeddingSize = 200

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=VocabSize, output_dim=EmbeddingSize, input_length=SizeOfInput))
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(SizeOfInput, EmbeddingSize), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(VocabSize, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

Tensorflow: 2.2.0

Python: 3.8

GPU: RTX2080Ti

I am training on 10000 randomly sampled sequences of 50 integers each epoch, from a larger dataset:

```
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=100, epochs=1)
```

I really don't know what the issue is, let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

1.Firstly please try your code in  [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

2.Try to use another optimizer:

```
keras.layers.BatchNormalization._USE_V2_BEHAVIOR = False
```

3.Maybe some ops running in cpu and some Ops are running in GPU.
In order to prevent it:

```
with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
    model.fit(x, y, batch_size=100, epochs=1)
```

3.Update the latest version of

```
tf-nightly-gpu 
tf-gpu 2.1 cudn 10.2
```

4.Test this:

```
print(tf.version.VERSION, tf.executing_eagerly(), keras.layers.BatchNormalization._USE_V2_BEHAVIOR)

keras.layers.BatchNormalization._USE_V2_BEHAVIOR = False
```

Comment: The model defined in the question does not use Batch Normalization, so what is the motivation for 2. and 4.?

Comment: I assume if you have BatchNormalization in your code.

Comment: You should not make such assumptions

Comment: There is not all of your code and I wanted to accelerate for your solution.

Comment: I am not the person that asked the original question.

Comment: Sure but in the end answers that are guessing are not really useful, specially as other people in the future will come and see your answer and think they solve the problem. I asked you what motivates changes in Batch Norm when the model in the question does not have Batch Norm, and this is a question other people will also have.

Comment: Batch Normalization is another layer. The use case is to use BN between the linear and non-linear layers in your network because it normalizes the input to your activation function so that you're centered in the linear section of the activation function (such as Sigmoid). You did not use it, but when training hangs on the model.fit() it is possible if someone used it and as alternative solution is useful to know if there is this layer make its param false. Sometimes in SO someone skips to write some line of code because they think it is not important while it is. I hope it helps.